# how to apply DRY principle to javascript and query

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I've got about 30 web pages, all of them HTML forms.  Each page has two or more different form elements - select, input text, checkboxes, text areas - along with various ui elements, popups, form validation etc.  I'm trying to refactor the jquery used in the pages to use the DRY principle but am not sure how to do it.  Here area few examples of some of the jquery used:

Example Code Block A:

```
    $(".show-tool", _container).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).nextAll(":hidden").css('display','block');
    });
```

Example Code Block B:

```
$(".optional").blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') 
    { 
        $(this).addClass('optional'); 
        $(this).val('(Optional)');
    }
});
```

Example Code Block C:

```
$('.howtoremain').click(function() {
    $('.hiddendiv').slideToggle("10000");
    if($(this).hasClass('howtoremain')) {
        $(this).removeClass('howtoremain').addClass('howtoremain2');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('howtoremain2').addClass('howtoremain');
    }
});
```

All of these are contained in the document.ready.  The actual code list above isn't that relevant.  I'm trying to have each HTML page only include the jquery code that is relevant.  For example page 1 might use code block A and B.  Page 2 might use A,B,C,D,E, and F.  Page 3 might use code block C and G.  Rather than have one giant document.ready with every code block (which will probably cause bugs at some point anyway if one code block needs to be slightly different than another for the same form element), how do you code this?  Have one javascript file per code block also seems lousy, as it would cause multiple hits to the server per page.  I think I am trying to get at one big javascript file, but only initialize in the document.ready those functions that are relevant to each page.

Comment: Paul Irish wrote a [great piece on this topic](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) back in 2009.

Comment: That was a great article.  I've implemented the ideas and now my code is much cleaner.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, I have gone over to using multiple JS-Files per module and concatenating them into a closure within a build process. This is similar to what jQuery does in its build process (cf. [intro.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/intro.js), [outro.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/outro.js))

This way, I can use granular, DRY modules in smaller files, then concatenate them. A typical single module file might look like this for your Example B:

```
( function($) {
    var subjects = $('.optional');
    if ( subjects.length === 0 ) {
        // this is a knockout criteria for this module, thus exit this enclosed function
        return;
    }

    subjects.blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') 
        { 
            $(this).addClass('optional'); 
            $(this).val('(Optional)');
        }
    });

    // now use whatever you need to initialise.
})($);
```

As you can see, I use the outer function not only to keep my scope clean, but much more important, to be able to cancel the module's initialisation as soon as I realise, it is not needed on the current page / event / ... - Of course, you may find several more efficient ways of determining whether or not each module should initialise itself.

On some projects, I have a build script to concatenate these modules within another closure which might look like this:

```
( function( window ) {
    var $ = window.jQuery; //call me paranoid, but I like my vars clean
    $(document).ready( function() {
        // stuff the modules here, one after another, in any sensible order.
    });
}(window);
```

In other projects, I am able to move the `$(document).ready()`-Bit into the modules where document.ready is needed, and listening to other Initialisation-Events within others, which feels a bit cleaner for me.

But anyway - having

- a build process rather than a lot of single requests
- several small, "one-thing-only"-Files to go into the build
- a self-enforced "top-level lambda function" due to the intro/outro-Concatenation-Style I adapted from jQuery itself

has significantly improved my DRY-ness and, even, my JS code style.